# Django formset - custom input HTML

Tags: django, formset

I need to expand a formset's field, so instead of

```
{{ form.name }}
```

I'm using something like

```
<input type="text" name="{{ form.name }}" ... >
```

My custom implementation does not print the formset prefix, so the HTML I get is

```
<input type="text" name="name" ... >
```

But what I would need to have the form working properly with formset is

```
<input type="text" name="attachments-3-name" ... >
```

where `attachments-x` is automatically added.

How can I get that?

I noted there's an helper for ID (`auto_id`) which prints something similar: `id_attachments-3-name`; is there something similar for names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `{{ form.name.html_name }}` is what I've been looking for the last 2 hrs.